# Using two を particles in one sentence

Tags: particles

When you left-click an image on the internet using chrome you are presented with, amongst others, this option:

> 名前を付けて画像を保存...

which I imagine is, in its full form

> 名前を付けて画像を保存する.

In this sentence, we have two を particles. Can someone please explain the details of this sentence grammar?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The important thing is the て-form from 付けて. It acts as a connection between the two separate clauses 名前を付ける and 画像を保存(する). You can think of it like the English `and` in this context. Naturally with two separate clauses, it's not at all surprising to have two をs.

Thus, to understand the sentence we just have to figure out what each of the parts mean. 名前を付ける means `to attach a name` and `画像を保存(する)` means to `save an image`. Thus this sentence means `to name and save an image`.

Comment: Additionally, in English the menu item would be "Save image as..." as opposed to "Save image"